# How to programmatically set "Enable field level fallback" field on a Template Field item?

Tags: language-fallback

I'm using sitecore 8.2.
I have a list of the Template Field items where I need to check the "Enable field level fallback" field programmatically.

So, something like that:

```
foreach (var item in ListOfItems)
{
    item.Fields["Enablefieldlevelfallback"].Value = "1";
    break;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you don't provide much of a context. But API wise, it would come out like this:

```
        foreach (Item item in ListOfItems)
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            item.Fields[FieldIDs.EnableLanguageFallback].Value = "1";
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
```

For the `Shared` version of Language Fallback, change the constant.

```
        foreach (Item item in ListOfItems)
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            item.Fields[FieldIDs.EnableSharedLanguageFallback].Value = "1";
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
```